# How to add a column giving the number of values >0 in each row to a table in R?

Tags: r

I have a table containing data that looks somewhat like this:

```
treatment, species1, species2, ... 
A, 3, 4, ... 
B, 2, 5, ...
```

I want to calculate the number of species per row and add the numbers calculated as a new column to the table, to make it look like this:

```
treatment, species1, species2, ... , number_of_species
A,         3,        4,        ... , 6
B,         2,        5,        ... , 9
```

I hope you understand what I aim at. As I'm new to R, I tried for some time and didn't find out, so help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Comment: Try `rowSums(df[,2:3])`, where `df` is your table. Look into `cbind` to merge the result into your `df`.

Comment: @rmk, make that an answer, I was just about to type it but you should get the credit.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question - Peter is asking for the number of distinct species in each treatment group, not the total number of animals observed (I'm guessing on the variable meanings here).

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far, and yes, you're right Matt, I'm looking for the number of distinct species, not the number of animals observed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this. It might take some tweaking to fit your data (it helps to provide some sample data with your question), but this should get you most of the way there.

```
# An easy way to make sample data
dat <- data.frame(treatment = letters[1:5],
                  species1 = c(3, 4, 0, 1, 3),
                  species2 = c(2, 1, 0, 0, 7),
                  species3 = c(0, 4, 0, 1, 0))

# First step: dat[ , -1] > 0 indicates which values are greater than zero
# You want to exclude the first column, since that just indicates 
# treatment group
dat[ , -1] > 0

# rowSums counts the number of values > 0 in each row - that's because, in R,
# you can add TRUE values to count them
rowSums(dat[ , -1] > 0)

# Finally, wrap it all up and add it to your data.frame
dat$number_of_species <- rowSums(dat[ , -1] > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your table is stored (this should work directly if it is the result of `table`, but could need some tweaking if it is a data frame or other structure), but it could be as simple as:

```
newtable <- addmargins(mytable, 1, FUN = function(x) sum( x > 0 ) )
```

Comment: Thank you as well, Greg, as my data is a data frame, this seems to need some tweaking. At least I didn't get it running. Thanks none the less, it seems like an elegant solution. :)